# Invert regexp in vim

Tags: regex, vim

There's a few "how do I invert a regexp" questions here on Stack Overflow, but I can't find one for vim (if it does exist, my Google-fu is lacking today).

In essence I want to match all non-printable characters and delete them. I could write a short script, or drop to a shell and use tr or something similar to delete, but a vim solution would be dandy :-)

Vim has the atom `\p` to match printable characters, however trying to do this  `:s/[^\p]//g` to match the inverse failed and just left me with every 'p' in the file. I've seen the `(?!xxx)` sequence in other questions, and vim seems to not recognize this sequence. I've not found seen an atom for non-printable chars.

In the interim, I'm going to drop to external tools, but if anyone's got any tricks up their sleeve to do this, it'd be welcome :-)

Ta!

Comment: Perl/pcre `(?!xxx)` expression has the same meaning as `\(xxx\)\@!` Vim expression, but I do not think that this will help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't put `\p` in character classes, although that would be a nice feature. However you can use the negative-lookahead feature `\@!` to build your search:

```
/\p\@!.
```

This will first make sure that the `.` can only match when it is not a `\p` character.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a little puzzled why you can't use the \p. But, [:print:] works fine:

```
:s/[^[:print:]]//g
```

Comment: This does not support unicode: `echo "Å"=~'[[:print:]]' "Å"=~'\p'` results in `0 1`.

Comment: @ZyX: Good catch. I wonder why `[:print:]` doesn't include printable unicode characters?

Comment: (Two years later)... I can't remember what version of Vim I originally asked this question of, but as of vim 7.3 (what I have installed at the moment), `[:print:]` does support Unicode, and the above from @ZyX now (correctly) returns `1 1`.

Comment: @ChrisJ No, it does not, at least on vim-7.3.462. You probably have problems with pasting. Try `echo "\u0410"=~'[[:print:]]' "\u0410"=~'\p'`, it tests CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A. The problem here has, I believe, the same roots as documented “Matching with a collection can be slow, because each character in the text has to be compared with each character in the collection.” problem: how do you imagine a set of all printable unicode characters? Set of *characters*, not *character ranges*. You can also see that `[\u0000-\u0100]` can match, but `[\u0000-\u0101]` is an error due to too wide range.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter file with Unicode (only if fileencoding=utf-8) printable characters, you could do this in three steps: mark all printable characters with not used UTF-8 symbol (for example, with `nr2char(0xFFFF)`), delete all characters, that are not followed by this symbol and, finally, delete this symbol:

```
%s/\p\@<=/<ffff>/g
%s/[^<ffff>]<ffff>\@!//g
%s/<ffff>//g
```

Here you must replace `<ffff>` with the actual character (if you type this, instead of `<ffff>` type `<C-r>=nr2char(0xFFFF)<CR>`).

If you are not working with Unicode use the dsummersl's answer.